# HTML5 Validate Input to accept alphabets only

Tags: html, input

I have an input firstname

```
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z]" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter on alphabets only. ')" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Firstname">
```

I enter it as : `qwerqwe`

I kept getting

`Please enter on alphabets only.` print out

[image]

Isn't `qwerqwe` suppose to be valid ? I'm a little confuse now, and not sure what I missed here.

Can someone please provide me some hints on this ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are allowing only ONE character. You missed the `+` sign:

```
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter on alphabets only. ')" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Firstname">
```

As [@le_m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647737/le-m) said in comments, you can write `*` wildcard to allow empty input:

```
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter on alphabets only. ')" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Firstname">
```

Comment: Incase anyone else is having problems with this. I had to use ^[a-zA-Z]+ to get this to work properly

Comment: In the event of an error, watching for new input and resetting the custom validity may be necessary: `oninput="setCustomValidity('')`

Answer (score 1):

use title attribute for validation name.

```
pattern="[A-Za-z0-9].{1,}" title="Please Enter Valid Company Name"
```

Comment: use title attribute for validation name.

Comment: .{1,} its means it will validate at least one or more characters and numbers

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your answer. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post

Answer (score 0):

Put a ^ on front of your patern.

Like so : ^[a-zA-Z]

Comment: What my pattern should look like ?

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z] *its Out of my Head but normaly this will work

Comment: Adding ^ has no effect since it is already implied, see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute